# Finding the perimeter of the required rectangle

Tags: geometry, maxima-minima, rectangles

A rectangle is inscribed within another rectangle of dimensions 6 units by 8 units. The rectangle has been inscribed in it with its vertices on the sides of the rectangle in such a way that if the smaller rectangle is rotated slightly about the centre it still is confined within the boundary of the larger rectangle. How can I find the minimum possible perimeter of such a rectangle? I am interested in an intuitive proof by simple geometry and not by coordinate geometry.

Comment: You mean "maximum" instead of "minimum"?

Comment: nope minimum perimeter only

Comment: that way, we can have a infinitesimally small rectangle!

Comment: By inscribed, do you mean that all four vertices are on the boundary of the given rectangle?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis yes I edited the question accordingly

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs No. The inscribed rectangle can rotate when it is almost as large as the main rectangle so you can get as close to 2(6+8) as you want. The minimum is much more interesting.

Comment: The minimum occurs when one pair of vertices are at the midpoints of the short sides of the main rectangle. If I did my arithmetic right, the sides of the inscribed rectangle are then $2 (\sqrt{7}-1)$
and $2(\sqrt{7}+1)$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis can you prove your statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, I think you are asking for the smallest circle that will fit into the 6x8 rectangle, and still touch all 4 sides.  Your rectangle is then the corresponding touch points that actually form a rectangle. Again, intuitively (without calculation) this seems to be the minimum perimeter. I think the calculation might be provided by Jaap in a comment. [image]